# How to use butterknife's Bind() in show dialog function in android

Tags: android, butterknife

This is my showDialog function, which gets call when someone clicks on a button in activity.

```
private void showCouponCodeDialog() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoge_apply_coupon);
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.coupon_code);

    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Button btnApplyCoupon = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnApplyCoupon);
    btnApplyCoupon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

when i do

```
@Bind(R.id.progressBar) ProgressBar progressBar;
```

It gives error @Bind not applicable to local variable.

This works fine.

```
final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

How to use butterknief's Bind() in this case?

Comment: Alternatively, you can declare `progressBar` as a field instead of a local variable.

Comment: but progreeBar is not part of activity. But is pert of R.layout.dialoge_apply_coupon.

Comment: you have to bind your view also with `Butterknife` with your `context`

Answer (score 0):

Using `Butterknife` you might use such bind methods:

```
Butterknife.bind(Dialog dialog)
```

or

```
Butterknife.bind (@NonNull Object target, @NonNull Dialog source)
```

The second one is better as it suggests, where (in which class) binds are hold. Remember, that those functions return `Unbinder` and it is really imprortant to unbind, when dialog is destroyed, otherwise memory leaks might occur.